# A gambler bet half his money at each toss of coin.If at the end of the game the wins and loses of the gambler are equal did he gain?

Tags: inequality

A gambler played the following game with a friend The gambler bet half the money in his pocket on the toss of a coin;he won on heads and lost on tails.The coin was tossed and the money handed over.The game was repeated,each time for half the money held by the gambler.At the end,the number of times the gambler lost was equal to the number of times he won.Did he gain,lose,or break even ?

> **Warning** : Below I have provided my thoughts and long speculations on the problem,so you may want to skip this part.I think it's important to note at least that this problem comes from the chapter of my book regarding inequalities.

---

I've not been able to make big progresses on this problem but rather I 've been speculating on the strategy to use.

My guess that he would break even but I am almost sure this is wrong.

Supposing that he wins and looses alternatively (i.e. after he wins he looses,and viceversa) ,I have (assuming now that he starts winning)

$$ \cfrac{m}{2} - \cfrac{m+\cfrac{m}{2}}{2} +\cfrac{ m +\cfrac{m}{2} -\left(\cfrac{m+\cfrac{m}{2}}{2}\right)}{2}-\cfrac{\cfrac{m}{2} - \cfrac{m+\cfrac{m}{2}}{2} +\cfrac{ m +\cfrac{m}{2} -\left(\cfrac{m+\cfrac{m}{2}}{2}\right)}{2}}{2}$$

which (if I am not making careless mistakes) breaks down to $$\cfrac{m}{2} -\cfrac{m}{2}-\cfrac{m}{4}+\cfrac{m}{2}+\cfrac{m}{4}-\cfrac{m}{4} -\cfrac{m}{8} +\cdots $$ and many things starts to cancel with simmetry,so this would lead me to think that whatever chain of wins and loses I have ,I can always arrange it so that I have the first chain above (that's a big jump of logic,I know). (It looks like I can always manipulate it to have a telescoping series)

I also have tried to see the proof of this by changing the order of wins and loses,i.e.

$$ \cfrac{m}{2} + \cfrac{m+\cfrac{m}{2}}{2} -\cfrac{ m +\cfrac{m}{2} -\left(\cfrac{m+\cfrac{m}{2}}{2}\right)}{2} + \cfrac{\cfrac{m}{2} + \cfrac{m+\cfrac{m}{2}}{2} -\cfrac{ m +\cfrac{m}{2} -\left(\cfrac{m+\cfrac{m}{2}}{2}\right)}{2}}{2} +\cdots$$

and this breaks down to $$\cfrac{m}{2} +\cfrac{m}{2}+\cfrac{m}{4}-\cfrac{m}{2}-\cfrac{m}{2}-\cfrac{m}{4}-\cfrac{m}{8}+\cfrac{m}{2} +\cdots$$

So my guess now would be that there's some way to make this look as the first one,but I don't know if this really is doable ,I am still working on this...

My last guess was that I could use AM-GM inequality or Cauchy inequality in some useful way sa this problem comes from the inequality chapter of my book,I can't see right away a nice way to apply them though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He will lose and you can compute the amount of the loss.  Each time he wins he multiplies his money by $\frac 32$.  Each time he loses he cuts it in half. The order of wins and losses does not matter because multiplication is commutative.  If there are $2n$ total tosses, he wins $n$ and loses $n$, so his fortune is mulitplied by $(\frac 32)^n(\frac12)^n=(\frac 34)^n \lt 1$

Comment: This was neat .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hint: start with a simple example. The gambler has 4 coins and he makes two bets. There are two options:

- The gambler gains 2, then loses 3. Net gain: -1.
- The gambler loses 2, then gains 1. Net gain: -1 again.

In this special case, the gambler loses. Since the question hints that the gambler always wins/loses/breaks-even, I would guess that the answer is "lose" also in the general case, and try to prove it.